# Sort a matrix based on the number of repeating elements in a particular column in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a matrix with only column labels, and I want to sort by column A, where repeating elements are ranked before non-repeating.  So because 7 appears four times in column A then is is moved to be in front of the rows with 2 in column A.  I hope this makes sense.

```
    A   B   C
    1   11  14
    2   2   2
    2   5   12
    2   13  2
    3   16  19
    3   10  0
    4   20  17
    5   5   16
    7   14  18
    7   8   10
    7   10  17
    7   7   0
```

Now, what I want it to look like is the following.

```
    A   B   C
    7   14  18
    7   8   10
    7   10  17
    7   7   0
    2   2   2
    2   5   12
    2   13  2
    3   16  19
    3   10  0
    1   11  14
    4   20  17
    5   5   16
```

Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: What's the rule for ties? smallest first?

Comment: This is weird - the rows in the input don't correspond to the rows in the output table!

Comment: You need to put in more effort either at constructing a valid example or in describing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're question needs to be a lot clearer. How are the values in `B` and `C` determined? From the description, it sounds like these should just be the corresponding values to those in the `A` column of the original data, but that's not the case in your example.

Until you clarify further, here's a way in base R that sorts the rows by `A` according to your condition.

```
d <- as.matrix(read.table(text="A   B   C
    1   11  14
    2   2   2
    2   5   12
    2   13  2
    3   16  19
    3   10  0
    4   20  17
    5   5   16
    7   14  18
    7   8   10
    7   10  17
    7   7   0", header=TRUE))

counts <- table(d[,'A'])
ranks <- rank(interaction(counts, names(counts), lex.order=TRUE))
d[order(ranks[match(d[,'A'], names(counts))], decreasing=TRUE), ]

#       A  B  C
#  [1,] 7 14 18
#  [2,] 7  8 10
#  [3,] 7 10 17
#  [4,] 7  7  0
#  [5,] 2  2  2
#  [6,] 2  5 12
#  [7,] 2 13  2
#  [8,] 3 16 19
#  [9,] 3 10  0
# [10,] 5  5 16
# [11,] 4 20 17
# [12,] 1 11 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
counts <- count(df, 'A')
df[order(merge(df, counts)$freq, decreasing=TRUE), ]
```